# There is some problem in otp verfication with pytotp?

Tags: authentication, flask, totp

I am using pytotp with flask.

Here is my basic code

```
@app.route('/get-otp-secret',methods=['POST'])
def getOTPSecret():

    return make_response(jsonify(generate_otp_secret()),201)

@app.route('/verify-otp',methods=['POST'])
def verifyOTP():
    print(request.form)
    otp,secret = request.form.get('otp'),request.form.get('secret')
    return jsonify(verify(otp,secret))

def generate_otp_secret():
    secret = pyotp.random_base32()
    t = pyotp.TOTP(secret,interval=60)
    otp = t.now()
    print(t.verify(otp))
    return {
        'secret':secret,
        'otp':otp
    }

def verify(otp,secret):
    if pyotp.TOTP(secret).verify(otp):
        return True
    return False
```

**Now, to check whether my secret and otp are same as generated I printed them.. and every thing is same.But pytotp is not verifying the otp.**
I there is something wrong in my method please tell me a correct way to implement pyotp.
I am sending request to flask from retrofit android studio java.
Thanks for helping me!!

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is on verify function, you don't add the 60 interval there?

```
def verify(otp,secret):
    if pyotp.TOTP(secret,interval=60).verify(otp):
        return True
    return False
```